# Can Convert.ChangeType be run in an unchecked context?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I have what is effectively a deserialization class for a custom messaging protocol. This class uses reflection to inspect the properties of the class and the attributes for the protocol mapping. This is working fine except when the value is an unsigned integer (32 or 64) and is being cast to an integer (32 or 64).

I could test (e.g. `if x is int`) the property types and branch off the code for these numeric types to perform casts in an `unchecked` block, but I would much rather keep the code simple and find a way to use the existing `Convert.ChangeType(value, convertToType)` logic. Is there a way to have this converter ignore numeric overflows? Or is there an alternative to casting using types known only at runtime?

NB: I realize that there is a root cause here that needs fixing but we do not currently have the ability to change the source of the data, the transport type or the messaging protocol.

Comment: What version of the framework are we talking?

Comment: Are you expecting that in your application the value of the `uint` will not be greater than `int.MaxValue`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.. but what do you gain by trying to abstract it away? I would say you lose the ability to see whats happening when you really should know..

Comment: Agreed. My instinct here is to fail in this situation rather than limp along knowing something is wrong (or will be wrong) but that's a different discussion

Comment: This is for .NET 4 and we do expect that values will be greater than int.MaxValue. This is a .NET client in a predominently c++ infrastucture and there is much legacy code depending on the result of casting uint to int in c++

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a developer instinct to not want to switch on the `is` keyword, been there myself. I would suggest doing it anyway. If you were not using reflection, I would understand the deliberation in introducing it, but if you are already using reflection anyway...

If you know (or guess) that the uint will not be larger than int.MaxValue, then you can use `Convert.ToInt32`. You should also catch the 'OverflowExceptions`, just in case.

Comment: The value can definitely be larger than int.MaxValue. If I knew all the different types I needed to handle at compile time I'd probably just suck it up and switch on `is` but I don't even know if the incoming values are numeric.

Comment: If the value can be larger than `int.MaxValue` then an int is not the correct way to store it on your end.

Comment: Just an observation: Your scenario seems complex enough to begin with. Sometimes you gotta get creative (and dirty) to deal with legacy code.

Comment: Agreed but, as I hoped my 'NB' would preempt, we don't have the ability to fix the root cause of this issue at this time. Never fear it will be resolved properly in due course. Even so, you're making quite a few assumptions; the behaviour is indeed 'correct' and expected in the c++ codebases.

Comment: Sorry if it came off judgey. I meant the opposite. I was saying "You got what you got" and now you need to make the best of it. In order to do that, you might need to get your c# side code a little dirty. I have been there, where something already passed QA and could not be changed until the next QA round, so you need to write "bridge" code, which you label as temporary, but ends up being permanent :)